# In Jest why can't I use beforeAll/beforeEach/afterAll/afterEach inside a single test. Error: Hooks cannot be defined inside tests

Tags: javascript, jestjs

In our project we have lots of tests and we have written some utility functions that use beforeAll/beforeEach/afterAll/afterEach methods to setup/teardown data that is common for multiple tests. This allows us to write tests like this:

```
describe('test suite', () => {
  addLocationSupport('/path')
  ...
  test('test 1', () => {
    // test using window.location
  });

  test('test 2', () => {
    // other test using window.location
  });
});
```

This all works as expected. However we have cases where we need to have this support for just a single test.

```
describe('test suite', () => {
  
  describe('for /path', () => {
    addLocationSupport('/path')

    test('test 1', () => {
      // test using window.location
    });

    test('test 2', () => {
      // other test using window.location
    });
  });
  
  test('for /other-path test 3', () => {
      addLocationSupport('/other-path')
  });
});
```

This does not work and throws an error:
`Error: Hooks cannot be defined inside tests. Hook of type "beforeAll" is nested within "for /other-path test 3"`
It forces us to wrap a single test in a single describe. The example is not really representative but we have complex trees of tests and it often doesn't make logical sense to introduce another describe as a wrapper just to have this support.
Any ideas on how to properly handle this are welcome.

for context:

```
const addLocationSupport = (url: string) => {
  const { location } = window;

  beforeAll(() => {
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
      configurable: true,
      enumerable: true,
      value: new URL(url),
      writable: true
    })
  });
  afterAll(() => {
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
      configurable: true,
      enumerable: true,
      value: location,
      writable: true
    })
  });

}url
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to override the location only for that test. The encapsualting/ describe will clean it for you. So you can have the following.

Keep in mind I have changed the beforeAll to beforeEach and afterAll to afterEach. We need that so that we can rested it for each test

```js
const setLocation = (url:string) => {
  window.location = {
      configurable: true,
      enumerable: true,
      value: new URL(url),
      writable: true
  };
}

const addLocationSupport = (url: string) => {
  const { location } = window;

  beforeEach(() => {
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {});
    setLocation(url);
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
      configurable: true,
      enumerable: true,
      value: location,
      writable: true
    })
  });

}
```

In your test:

```js
describe('test suite', () => {
  addLocationSupport('/path');
  
  test('for /other-path test 3', () => {
      setLocation('/other-path')
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this was the issue (simplified):

```
function initFunc() {
  beforeEach(() => {})
}

someAsyncFn().then(initFunc)
```

The beforeEach here is called after the promise is resolved and this can happen **during** the test.